# How to remove items from menu based on user permissions in asp.net master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu

```
 //Create user, create group
            else if ((PermissionList.Any(item => item.Equals("Create group"))) && (PermissionList.Any(item => item.Equals("Create user"))) && (PermissionList.Any(item => item.Equals("Create message"))))
            {
 NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
                {
                    Text = "Users",
                    NavigateUrl = "~/Users.aspx"
                });
                NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
                {
                    Text = Groups",
                    NavigateUrl = "~/Groups.aspx"
                });
            }


           <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" RenderingMode="Table" CssClass="menu"
                    EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
```

I am adding items to the menu based on the user permission, here Since I have many combination of permission I have to do many condition and it is more than 20 combination. so for each combination I am executing code to add items to the menu, how can I add all menu items and remove the one for which the users doesnt have permission. Ex if the menu items are 
"groups, users, message, support" then if the user permission is "create user", then I should remove groups and messages from the menu, How can i do that.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure on the specifics of how your logic works, but in the same way you're using the `Add` method for the `Items` collection of your menu, you can use the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitemcollection.remove.aspx) or [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitemcollection.removeat.aspx) methods to take menu items away.

So, something like

```
if( Some Condition that means the user shouldn't have the "Message" privilege)
{
    NavigationMenu.Items.RemoveAt(messageMenuItemIndex);
}
```